# How to display entries with a custom date field within month

Tags: datetime, date

I've got a date field, and I'm grabbing the month and year from the url. What I'm after is to display all the events within the month, but for some reason I can't get this to work

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = month ~ "/1/" ~ year|date("U") %} // returns the 1st day of the month in unixtime

{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth = month ~ "/" ~ daysInThisMonth ~ "/" ~ year|date("U") %} // returns the last day of the month in unixtime

{% set thisMonthsEvents = craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}

{% if thisMonthsEvents | length %}
    some events
{% else %}
    no events
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas? firstDayOfMonth and lastDayOfMonth return dates fine, but no matter how I format them, the result is no entries returned. For example, firstDayOfTheMonth could output "2014-6-01" and lastDayOfMonth could output "2014-6-30", and I've got an event with an eventDate of 18th June 2014, but nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The problem with your code is, that you apply the `date` filter exclusively to the year variable:

> `{% set firstDayOfMonth = month ~ "/1/" ~ year|date("U") %}`

To get this right you have to first compose your "datetime string" and then apply the filter to the string as a whole:

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = (month ~ "/1/" ~ year)|date("U") %}
```

That's also the reason why it works for you to apply it inside the query.

.

**Solution 2:**

You don't need to pass a unix datetime formated string to your query, a string in format "Y-m-d" is just fine:

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-01" %}
{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}

{% set lastDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ daysInThisMonth %}

{% set thisMonthsEvents = craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use the unix time format. Try `|date('Y-m-d')` instead of `|date("U")`.

.

*Edit:*

You actually don't need to use the `|date` filter for that:

```
{% set year = 2014 %}
{% set month = 06 %}

{% set firstDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-01" %}
{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}

{% set lastDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ daysInThisMonth %} 

{{ firstDayOfMonth ~ " - " ~ lastDayOfMonth }}
```

Comment: This has the same effect - no results when I know there should be. It outputs the dates correctly, but treurns no entries. I think the problem is the way I'm using the dates?

Comment: @ClivePortman Can close your query with ) and add a .find() at the end?

Comment: @Victor_In Have updated question so it includes the closing ). Adding .find() makes no difference.

Comment: @Clive I suppose you just replaced "/" with "-" and didn't try that code as a whole. It definitely works, see my other answer for more info! :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's the answer:

```
{% set thisMonthsEvents = craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth | date("U"), '<=' ~ lastDayOfMonth | date("U")) %}
```

Maybe this has something to do with me not formatting firstDayOfMonth and lastDayOfMonth as dates within the original query? Also, why doesn't this need a .find() after it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. The only difference to the initial code is that you now apply the date filter inside the query or even twice?!

Comment: Adding .find() was just a guess, but soon we will know the answer: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/265/177