# Return entries with startDate or endDate within a calendar year

Tags: datetime, date, conditional, logic, queries

I have two date fields in my entry and I want to return those entries with either a start date OR and end date within a calendar year.

I can get those with a startDate within the calendar year using:

```
{% set nextyear = year +1 %}
{% set yearbegins = '1 January ' ~ year %}
{% set yearends = '1 January' ~ nextyear %}
{% set unixbegins = yearbegins | date("U") %}
{% set unixends = yearends | date("U") %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null).startDate('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends) %}
```

How to I then run a test on endDate to further filter them down?

Comment: How come this code works for you now? I think you had to use the `date('U')` filter inside the query as you wrote [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/264/125)?

Comment: I don't know. I was surprised to find that happen in the other post, too. When I get chance I'll review it, but this is a different template.

Comment: thanks a lot. your code got me started for my own project. but where does this syntax come from (cf_date('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends, '< ' ~ now))? are there any docs on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do two queries to get the Ids of the desired entries, [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) the Ids and then query the entries with these Ids:

```
{# Get Ids of desired entries #}
{% set startDateIds = craft.entries.startDate('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends).ids() %}
{% set endDateIds = craft.entries.endDate('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends).ids() %}

{# Merge queried Ids #}
{% set filteredIds = startDateIds|merge(endDateIds) %}

{# Get entries with Id paramenter #}
{% set filteredEntries = craft.entries.id(filteredIds) %}
```

.

Another idea is to query all potential entries, loop those and filter within the loop. This is probably the way to go if you need to combine your conditionals with [other logic](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#logic) then the `and` operator:

```
{# Get all potential entries #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null).find() %}

{# Define array before loop #}
{% set filteredEntries = {} %}

{# Loop all entries #}
{% for key, entry in allEntries %}

    {# Set conditionals to filter for desired entries #}
    {% if ( entry.startDate >= unixbegins and entry.startDate < unixends ) and ( entry.endDate >= unixbegins and entry.endDate < unixends ) %}

        {# Merge entries #}
        {% set filteredEntries = filteredEntries|merge({ (key): entry }) %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Error: The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes. Both entriesStartDate and entriesEndDate return a llist of entries correctly.

Comment: Actually, I don't want merge, do I? I only want entries which in both entriesStartDate and entriesEndDate.

Comment: Hmm, you wrote "with either a start date OR and end date within a calendar year" that means all entries with a start date in that year PLUS all entries with an end date in it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I do need merge. As long as they aren't repeated.

Comment: Yep, the new improved merge solved it. Thanks.

Comment: That's good to hear, @Clive. I'll delete that old code for clarity.

Comment: Just so you know, there's something in lines 2 and 3 of your first answer which knackers a Bootstrap column for Webkit browsers. I don't know quite where is was, but typing them out rather than pasting them fixed it.