# Advanced Entry Queries

Tags: entries, search

I'm looking to write advanced nested search queries in Craft.

For example, below I'm looking to find results that have a `featuredContent` value of 1 **and** an `endDate` after today **or** empty. In psuedo code, `(this == 1 AND (that = foo OR that = bar )`.

`{% set params = {
  section : 'sectionName',
  orderBy : 'startDate asc',
  featuredContent : "1",
  endDate : ">= " ~ now|date('Y-m-d') ~ ' OR :empty:'
} %}`

`{% set results = craft.entries(params).all() %}`

Sadly, this doesn't work. Do I need to write this as a `search` function? If so, how?

A related question might be: is there a way to directly use MySQL WHERE queries to return entries via TWIG? This would be super helpful at times..

Comment: Take a look at https://tighten.co/blog/craft-cms-building-complex-queries-by-extending-the-elementcriteriamodel and https://github.com/tightenco/craft-build-query for info on building more direct queries from Twig.

Comment: Looked here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21961/how-to-check-for-a-value-or-null-on-custom-enddate-field-using-yii-syntax-when-c to no avail. The answer provided there does not work... Braking this up into two queries for now. Any further suggestions welcome.