# Is it possible to compose a DateTime object from a string?

Tags: templating, datetime, variable

I experienced that there is a difference between real DateTime objects (as `now` is one) and strings composed to "fake DateTime objects" (ie. `{% set myDate = '2014/06/24' %}`).

Sometimes it makes no difference and you can use one or the other. The `date()` filter for example works fine with both. But this isn't always the case, the `localeTime()` method is an example that exclusively takes real DateTime objects.

Applying a `date` or `date_modify` filter to the `myDate` (string) variable is apparently not sufficient to convert it. The only solution I found is to modify `now` or fetch a DateTime object from an entry field, but I am looking for a way to generate one solely with twig in the template.

.

*Edit:*

Thanks for your answers so far, but I still don't get this to work. For me it always results in the following template error when I use a [DateTime method](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/datetime#methods) on a manually composed DateTime object:

> Method "localeTime" for object "DateTime" does not exist

Here my example code for easy reproducibility. I more and more believe this is rather a problem with those [DateTime methods](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/datetime#methods) and not with the way I compose the object.

```
{# Set var to string in supported format #}
{% set myDatetimeString = '2014-06-24 23:40' %}

{# Use date() function to convert string to DateTime object #}
{% set myDatetimeObject = date(myDatetimeString) %}

{# Alternatively use date_modify filter to convert string to DateTime object #}
{% set myDatetimeObject = myDatetimeString|date_modify('+0 day') %}


{# DateTime method doesnt work with these "objects" !! #}
{{ myDatetimeObject.localeTime() }}

{# But DateTime methods work with the `now` DateTime object #}
{{ now.localeTime() }}
{{ now.day() }}
{{ now.iso8601() }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Twig, the `date_modify` filter returns a DateTime object. Also, `date` is not just a filter, but also a function. The `date` function accepts any a DateTime object or a string in a [supported format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), and returns a DateTime object. Example:

```
{{ date("+2 years") }}
```

This should give you a DateTime object set for 2 years from when it's triggered.

**Why is localeTime missing?**

The `now` variable is not a regular DateTime object from PHP. It's actually an extended class ( \Craft\DateTime ). So it won't have all the convenience functions you get from `now` or a date field from an entry. Instead you would need to do it manually (I'm not sure if you can overwrite a function or filter in Twig). Fortunately, the locale's format string is available as a variable.

```
{% set myDatetimeString = '2014-06-24 23:40' %}
{% set format = craft.i18n.getTimepickerJsFormat() %}
{{ myDatetimeString|date(format) }}
```

You can even shorten it like this:

```
{% set myDatetimeString = '2014-06-24 23:40' %}
{{ myDatetimeString|date(craft.i18n.getTimepickerJsFormat()) }}
```

To replicate localeDate, use this:

```
{% set myDatetimeString = '2014-06-24 23:40' %}
{{ myDatetimeString|date(craft.i18n.getDatepickerJsFormat()) }}
```

Comment: These DateTime objects don't work with `localeTime()` methods for me.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach I gotcha now. I have edited my response to fill the missing information.

Comment: Great Bryan, thanks a lot! But that first sentence confuses me, sure you mean `now` variable?

Comment: Yes. `now` is listed as a Global Variable in the [Docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables).

Comment: Bryan, does this still work for you? Tried it again today and noticed that `craft.i18n.getDatepickerJsFormat()` outputs a format like this `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `d/m/Y`?! Which makes it useless for the date filter :(

Comment: I haven't used much date stuff recently, but I'll be creating a simple Events section tonight for a new site. I'll check it out then.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, starting with a string:

```
{% set yearbegins = '1 January ' ~ year %} // getting year from a url (dynamic route)
{{ yearbegins | date("U") }} // outputs the date in Unixtime
```

Are you saying this is not a real datetime object, and it's just the date filter making it look like it? I'm finding some unpredictability, too, as you know.

Comment: In my question I already described that the `date` filter works for me to. It's the `localeTime()` method I have problems with. And in regards to that DateTime problem you encountered, I think I solved that one! See my [new answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/447/125). ;)