# How do I filter entries by month using custom Date/Time field and paginate them?

Tags: entries, templating, filter

Here is how I am filtering entries by a specific month:

```
{% set filterId = "July" %}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('messages') %}
{% set filteredEntries = [] %}

{% for msg in allEntries %}

  {% if msg.messageDate | date('F') == filterId | date('F') %}
    {% set filteredEntries = filteredEntries | merge([msg]) %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% set messageList = filteredEntries %}
```

How can I paginate messageList? Do I need to filter by month a different way for pagination to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to paginate messageList, because that's just an array... According to the [official documentation on the `{% paginate %}` tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate#parameters), only an **ElementCriteriaModel** can be paginated.

To see how to create an ElementCriteriaModel which has already been filtered by month, check out [Solution #2 in this thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/447/45)

You'll end up with code that looks something like this:

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-01" %}
{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth  = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ daysInThisMonth %}

{% set thisMonthsEntries = craft.entries.section('messages').messageDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}

{% paginate thisMonthsEntries as entriesOnPage %}
    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
        {# ... whatever your code does... #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: You're very welcome! :)

Comment: Is it possible to only compare to the month itself so that it finds all entries in that month regardless of year?

Comment: The code to pull that off would be very different from what we've got here... This example creates a date **range** (from the 1st - 31st of a given month). What you just described would actually look for multiple ranges across X years. Since the pagination portion of this question has already been answered, I'd suggest posing that as a fresh question.